# og:video:height being ignored

Tags: flash, facebook

I have the OG meta tags on my page and everything is working nicely. When people like the video on the page, the player is embedded in facebook. BUT it seems to be ignoring the og:video:height meta tag. The video is being displayed in facebook with a height of 259 rather than the og:video:height of 117 set int he page.

This seems to have only been an issue recently.

I also noticed that youtube videos embedded in facebook also have a height of 259. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with facebook.   The open graph way of specifying height isn't working for anyone right now.   regardless of what is set, the height becomes 259.   the only way i was able to get anything to post was via the graph api method using "expanded_height" and "expanded_width".

My site had 398X398 dimensions and we didn't change anything then all of the sudden our height was scaled down.

I was going mad for a while, but i'm fairly certain this is a bug with facebook's open graph implementation or an undocumented change.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of...Now I see this bug report: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19972 thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following tags, as I am not sure the ones you are using are correct.

```
<meta name="og:video" content="blah"></meta>
<meta name="video_style" content="blah"></meta>
<meta name="video_height" content="blah"></meta>
<meta name="video_width" content="blah"></meta>
```

Comment: here's the source, everything works except the height http://www.kogeto.com/videos3.php

Comment: As mentioned, changed your meta tags to the ones I pointed out and it should work.  Those are the ones I use.

Comment: I'll give it a try...what goes in the video_style tag? I don't see documentation for that anywhere

Comment: This was an old tag that I have kept since it has changed. It isn't necessary.  Just a question on the og:video:height, did you make 259 a string, like so: <meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />

Comment: yeah in my HTML I have:

<meta property="og:video:width" content="398" /> 
<meta property="og:video:height" content="177" />

I added your tags and ran it through the facbook linter, posted the link to my wall and the same thing happened.

then in facebook it comes out with a width of 398 and a height of 259.

Comment: I just tried posting it to my wall and it worked, though the image before the video was in the wrong proportion, the video itself were in the right dimensions.

Comment: yeah that's the problem, the initial screen (in flash) before the video plays is sized to a height of 259 even though my og:video:height is 177.

Comment: og:image needs a max 3:1 ratio, being that it is more, it likely is the reason Facebook is resizing it.

Comment: the screen you are seeing once it expands is not an image, it's flash. The og:image is just used for the thumbnail

Comment: I am aware, the image must be a max of 3:1, that is the one that doesn't have a proper aspect ratio, the video does.

Comment: I changed the size of the image, didn't seem to help.